# How to convert NuGet package to npm

Tags: npm, nuget, nuget-package

I need to convert/repackage NuGet package to npm package. Has anyone tried this before?

Is there any automatic tool that exist? (At least for simple cases with no dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain the package contents with a package.json file in a git repo and register the repo in npm registry to publish it to npm.

UG: [publishing-npm-packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages)